# Fully corrupted workspace in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I just want to use eclipse without any <del>fckin</del> workspace errors (I settle for in-project errors). But it says followings on every <del>fckin</del> start-up. I'm going to be insane.

[image: fckin errors]

Thanks in advance. My system is **Windows 7 x64**.

Comment: That means it's time to assume the fetal position and weep into your knees. Then again, just using Eclipse should've gotten you to that stage already.

Comment: @Nil eclipse isn't that bad. And Mehmet why not just create a new workspace?

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven Hi, how can I do that?

Comment: Just select switch workspace under the new menu, and import your projects into the new workspace.

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven Thanks it worked, but one more problem. When I create a new project and a new activity class, it says "MainActivity does not extend android.app.Activity". It extends SimpleBaseGameActivity.

Comment: Odd, that class should extend  BaseGameActivity, which extends BaseActivity, which extends Activity. Have you tried a project clean?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it says "does not extend android.app.Application" not "android.app.Activity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanking after cursing seems weird but here is answer:

Eclipse errors can be persistent.
Exit Eclipse and then re-run Eclipse.
From the Eclipse menu, select Project, Clean.
Finally select Run (even if you have errors) to clear out any remaining false errors.

if(solution above does not solve)
{

Download fresh eclipse.

Copy and paste your codes(not files) into the to-be-newly created project-classes inside. Enter the necessary path variables from project settings. Then save/run. 
If still error happens, look inside codes and plugin settings.

Check for other projects that are using same resources.(could be the issue)

}